# Wird "blankziehen" seit kurzem häufiger verwendet?

Tags: phrase

Bis vor ein paar Monaten hatte ich den Ausdruck

> blankziehen

für "sich ausziehen" (insbesondere nackt ausziehen) nicht einmal gehört. Seitdem kommt mit der Ausdruck aber immer öfter in den Medien unter (insbesondere auf gmx, z.B. [hier](http://www.gmx.at/magazine/unterhaltung/lifestyle/model-gerne-blank-18737628))

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/blankziehen) wird blankziehen streng genommen nur im Zusammenhang mit Schwertern etc. benutzt.

Da ich die meiste Zeit in Österreich verbracht habe, würde ich gerne wissen, ob das in Deutschland oder ev. auch in der Schweiz schon länger ein gängiger Begriff im Zusammenhang mit Kleidung ist.

Comment: Das könnte selektive Wahrnehmung sein. Siehe auch [hier](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5418/42471).

Comment: Könnte sein, deshalb frage ich hier nach. Insbesondere weil ich mich nicht erinnern kann, den Ausdruck in meinen ersten 34 Lebensjahren gehört zu haben.

Comment: Seit allenfalls 10 Jahren kenne ich den Begriff, nahezu ausschließlich vom Bildblog für "den Busen entblößen". In der Umgangssprache habe ich es noch nie gehört; gedruckt gesehen aber auch vor über 10 Jahren nicht. Außer im Zusammenhang mit Schwertern, natürlich. Die aggressive Komponente stößt mich ab.

Comment: Blankziehen kenne ich auch als Synonym für "Die Karten offenlegen", "Mit der Wahrheit rausrücken", ...

Comment: @userunknown Ich sehe den Begriff auch fast immer im Zusammenhang mit Models/Promis, die sich entblößen.

Comment: Sex sells. Ist nun mal der stärkste Trieb in der Fauna.  Das wissen die Leute, die anderen etwas zu verkaufen suchen, ganz genau. Und wenn dann der eher Unbedarfte sogar im altehrwürdigen Duden _"aus der Scheide ziehen"_ liest und ein Schwert durchaus auch als phallisches Symbol betrachtet werden kann, ist es zur Verwendung in rein sexuellem Bezug nicht mehr weit. Man kann nun _O tempora, o mores_ deklamieren aber diese, genau wie Sprache, sind nun mal einem stetigen Wandel unterworfen. → ...

Comment: ... → Das geht auch mir machmal gegen den Strich (Schon wieder so ein Wort! :-) aber ich bin ehrlich genug, um einzugestehen, dass ich mich, aus meiner subjektiven Sicht, mit dem Wissen um eigentliche Hintergründe von denen, die es anscheinend oder auch nur scheinbar nicht wissen, abhebe. Was natürlich meinem Ego schmeichelt und mich mit stoischer innerer Ruhe die äußerlichen Zeitgeistigkeiten recht gut ignorieren lässt. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Duden-Definition ist mir tatäschlich neu. Könnte daran liegen, dass ich es nicht so mit Schwertern habe. Ich hab *blankziehen* im Kontext *sich ausziehen* aber schon häufig gehört.

Laut NGram-Viewer gibt es den Begriff schon etwa 100 Jahre. Interessanterweise beziehen  sich aktuelle Suchergebnisse zumeist auf Degen oder Schwert.

In der Umgangssprache hingegen wird nahe zu einzig von *sich ausziehen* geredet.<sup>1</sup> (Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass jemand, der Rollenspiele betreibt, dies anders sieht.)

Einen Trend hin, den Begriff häufiger zu verwenden, empfinde ich nicht. Sprich, ich höre den Begriff heutzutage genau so regelmäßig wie vor 10 oder 15 Jahren.

---

<sup>1</sup> Diese Aussage trifft für den Westen Deutschlands zu und ich vermute auch für den Norden.

Comment: Ich würde die Aussage auch für Sachsen unterschreiben. Naja, in dem Sinn, dass sich jemand auszieht, ohne dass die Umstehenden kontextbezogen damit gerechnet haben. Es ist jedoch nicht völlig absurd.

Comment: Für Süddeutschland stimme ich auch zu. Kommt in der Umgangssprache nicht vor, auch bei meinem 20jährigen Sohn nicht.

Answer (score -3):

Du hast Recht. Der Begriff zieht seit Monaten durch die Boulevardpresse und erhält so einen neuen Bedeutungszusammenhang. Er wird damit eingereiht in die Neologismen, also in den Bereich der Kunstworte. Meiner Meinung nach sind diese Wortschöpfungen noch nicht Mal originell, sondern nur billig immer weiterverbreitet und irgendwann Bestandteil des Sprachschatzes.

https://www.kunst-worte.de/neologismen/neologismus-62-blankziehen/

Comment: Blankziehen in der Verwendung von sich ausziehen oder nackte Haut zeigen gibt's es schon deutlich länger als nur ein paar Monate

Comment: Ein Neologismus ist auch kein Kunstwort sondern eine Wortneuschaffung. Ob du es originell findest oder nicht ist weiterhin nicht von Belang, aber wenn du es für nötig hälst soll es von mir aus im Post stehen bleiben

Comment: Ja, nach 5 Jahren beizupflichten mit der Einschränkung "seit Monaten" ist eigentlich ein Widerspruch. Sich mit dem Nick Grammarwhore darüber zu echauffieren, es sei nicht mal originell, dagegen ist originell. :)